# Why doesn't a button change the layout?

Tags: android, button, layout, user-interface

I would like to press a button and for a new layout to appear.

What am I doing wrong?

My class names are: StarWars.java and Test1.java
Layout names: activity_star_wars-.xml and test1.xml

My code:

```
package de.starwars;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_star_wars);

Button jm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btxJediMaster);
jm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent (StarWars.this,Test1.class);
        startActivity(i);       
}
});

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_star_wars, menu);
    return true;
}  
}
```

The manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="de.starwars.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? what exception are you getting?

Comment: you appear to be extremely confused about what you're doing (no offense).  Why do you have your code in the onCreateOptionsMenu callback? That deals with the system menu... are you really trying to inflate a view into the system menu? I suspect not (and if you are, then that won't work).  Please describe in detail what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: You sound a little confused yourself, genius.

Comment: Have you made sure both activities Starwars and Test1 are added to your AndroidManifest.xml? (example '<activity android:name=".Starwars" />' and '<activity android:name=".Test1" />'

Comment: Basicly I want, that if I hit the button "btxJediMaster", a new layout should appear. So I want to do a quiz. JediMaster is a one of four difficulties. So after I click the button, a new layout with a question should appear. I hope you understand now a little bit better what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
jm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btxJediMaster);
    jm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(StarWars.this,Test1.class);
            StarWars.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);

        }
    });
```

and the `manifest`:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name="de.starwars.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="de.starwars.Test1"/>
</application>
```

Comment: I changed it, but I still get: "The application StarWars(process de.starwars)has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

Comment: Have you added the new activity in the manifest?

Comment: No I didnt.. I added the manifest in my post above. What do I actually have to change? I´m right now a newbie to the whole android development, so I´m sorry if some of my questions appears realy stupid- I just want to learn and do it right.

Comment: Check my edited answer, now it should work.

Comment: Just one more thing, could you explain me what you actually did? So I see that you changed, but could you explain why you did this, this would be very helpful :)

Comment: I recommend you to take a look a this http://developer.android.com/training/index.html. Here you can find some guides. Anyway if my answer was useful for you click to set it like accepted answer.